# Protobuf-net serialize by category/mask

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

This question might be easiest with a concrete example. I have a class representing a player controllable unit in a game. When I serialize this unit to disk I want to save everything. When I send a network update to other players i want to send a subset of 'everything' including only things which I know have changed.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Unit
{
   [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired=false)
   public Vector3 Position;

   [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired=false)
   public Unit Target;
}
```

And so on, all member are marked optional, so on the receiving end it will properly decode a message regardless of if it contains a Position update, a Target update, or both.

But.. how do I serialize a message which doesn't contain all members marked with [ProtoMember]?

Keep in mind this is going to occur in performance critical code locations that also cannot be making heap allocations, and I may want any arbitrary combination of 20+ different properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf-net supports the pre-existing pattern (used by a few other serializers / UI tools):

```
public bool ShouldSerializeTarget() {...}
public bool ShouldSerializePosition() {...}
```

Note: the methods can be private, except on runtimes with enforced access checks.

In terms of controlling the options - I'd probably use a flags enum:

```
return (serializeFlags & UnitMembers.Target) != 0;
```

With

```
[Flags]
public enum UnitMembers {
    None =0,
    Position = 1,
    Target = 2,
    // 4, 8, 16, 32, etc
}
```

That allows you to control 32 members in the space of an `int`-based enum, or 64 members in the space of a `long`-based enum.

Comment: How does Protobuff-net know to call the ShouldSerializeXXX methods? A magic attribute or some such? Oh, just looked it up, apparently it just naming convension based... weird.

Comment: @James no, it is a name-based convention that started in PropertyDescriptor (System.ComponentModel), and is used by XmlSerializer and a range of other tools.

Comment: I have two concerns... i bet its doing slow methodinfo.invoke calls, and its also rather ugly to have an additional method for every property. Ideally it would be like... my class implements `bool IFoo.ShouldSerialize(int flag)` but don't suppose that exists.

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer, unless you are aware of any alternatives? I may dig into where you implemented this and see about adding an IShouldSerialize interface. Note this would also eliminate the need for my own book-keeping enum, since they already have a unique int (ProtoMemberAttribute.Flag) that can be passed as the argument.

Comment: @James no, it isn't using reflection invoke; the library uses extensive IL generation